# How to update the data frame value based on change in next data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df 1=

    as_date     end_date     pdate            A      b
0   05/11/2021  05/31/2021   05/08/2020      0.6    0.9
1   05/11/2021  05/31/2021   05/09/2020      0.8    0.4
2   05/12/2021  05/31/2021   05/10/2020      0.4    0.6
3   05/12/2021  05/31/2021   05/11/2020      0.5    0.4

df2=

    as_date     end_date        pdate          A     b
0   05/11/2021  05/11/2021  05/08/2021        1.6   0.9
1   05/11/2021  05/11/2021  05/09/2021        0.8   1.4
2   05/12/2021  05/11/2021  05/10/2021        1.4   0.6
```

if the change in the value of column A and column B of the df2 then the change in the value row to the df1 rows the column end date is updated based on the df2
output

```
    as_date     end_date     pdate            A      b
0   05/11/2021  05/08/2021   05/08/2020      0.6    0.9
1   05/11/2021  05/09/2021   05/09/2020      0.8    0.4
2   05/12/2021  05/10/2021   05/10/2020      0.4    0.6
3   05/12/2021  05/31/2021   05/11/2020      0.5    0.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
df2.columns += '_x' # To make it easier to concat
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df1['end_date'] = np.where(df1.pdate_x.isna(),df1.end_date,df1.pdate_x)
df1 = df1.dropna(axis=1)

## Renaming columns of df2 as before
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace('_x','', regex=True) 
df1
```

**Output**

```
    as_date     end_date    pdate       A   b
0   05/11/2021  05/08/2021  05/08/2020  0.6 0.9
1   05/11/2021  05/09/2021  05/09/2020  0.8 0.4
2   05/12/2021  05/10/2021  05/10/2020  0.4 0.6
3   05/12/2021  05/31/2021  05/11/2020  0.5 0.4
```

**Explanation**

We are `concatenating df1 and df2` and then replacing `end_date of df1` with `pdate of df2` using `np.where`.